# Can't Open File download from browser

Tags: android

I have download application from FTP server. After successfully downloaded apk from server, when I clicked on it then it gives me error "Can't Open File". As you can see in Screen shot.

When I open **Downloads** application and then try to install the application from there then also it gives same error.

[image]
[image]

But when I try with File Manager and try to install it then it is getting installed. Does anybody have any idea what is the cause for this?

Can you please suggest why I can't install the application from the Notification section after the download is completed or from the inbuilt **Downloads** application?

Comment: I'm not sure this is the right forum for this type of question. I would try android.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 3):

> 1. I had this problem. Couldn't install apk via the Downloads app. However opening the apk in a file manager app allowed me to install it
>      fine. Using **OI File Manager** on stock Nexus 7 4.2.1.

or

> 2. It shouldn't be HTTP headers if the file has been downloaded successfully and it's the same file that you can open from OI.
>
> A shot in the dark, but could it be that you are not allowing
>   installation from unknown sources, and that OI is somehow bypassing
>   that?
>
> Settings > Applications > Unknown sources...